# Remove the equals sign and the number and + sign after it from a string file

Tags: regex, replace, find, textpad

I have a file that has custom retails that I need to remove for order processing. The retails are in a format w/out the decimal and pertain to the item number proceeding it. I need to just be left with the item numbers between the `+`

Here is what I have to edit: Example `=39759` remove it and leave one plus sign to join the part numbers

```
F061100+00143271H5+132103491+084002361+=39759+086074002+142213781+142204382+1422050310+=3499+142236976+=3499+142223016+1422079210+=3899+202410636+202406854+=31999+202407688+=31899+251151481+173111351+=32499+1731231512+171621571+233009652+109214923+177000892+=32099+207445381+=31439+207412032+=3959+199009196+1690004530+132019422+=32899+248030091+=3999+134100712+=31499+171506401+=31199+136238891+140313063+140064232+155423682+155400992+159613453+165232351+165216681+3700165812+165246391+102040551+=31979+102019862+106123802+106143941+102012261+106113253+=31299+106115151+106117961+=31799+106101372+=32899+106115231+=31699+106416942+=31299+106307215+=3799+106400435+=31899+106302833+=31899+106411815+=31499+108014964+102441926+=3199+159355546+159361154+159332033+159321636+159317281+159356536+3640211312+1592259410+=3159+1592053110+1592052320+=3139+084006811+=31599+159297891+203036321+=32999+1653022212+=3899+161204381+159186594+159157213+159157475+=3259+159278336+1615154010+1592354320+1592642110+170110161+159304235+159397962+159605453+157238931+=32599+332618191+=31399+332603651+170105211+159309934+159320073+159323533+159009391+101215981+=32699+237003391+=31599+2026035212+=3379+125256714+202100191+=31599+319006656+190238293+=3299+0200147724+=3199+237008002+=3939+199625052+=3499+086021952+322044634+086036494+161006535+=31499+102105245+=3999+101203761+198203643+=31059+193034863+193031893+193045343+=3439+206116871+159324942+=3379+159355626+203004711+=31899+157316314+=3579+249512041+358029666+1653002412+1611167615+157242711+=37659+161425156+1593431810+=3539+1593423510+226113472+205184373+=31299+358059366+=3439+370105431+212002253+=31399+209204192+=31799+171321192+084005171+=34999+10244077100+105122755+=3239+1290210212+=31099+129102043+=31799+134122181+138452196+=3599+138468866+140240791+=35999+163034301+=313999+173143942+=31099+1733057212+1733059812+1733062212+176302606+190208253+226124934+237001156+=3299+248030173+=31299+251151303+261694905+=3739+2662005412+2662022912+266209142+2662260512+=3539+275040421+=31939+2753081512+275342056+=3839+275374066+=3639+311101741+311215026+311215366+311215446+326309803+364201316+3700144312+=3379+3700146812+3700155912+=3379+374200231+396003414+396023541+=31039+428241282+=31399+173133132+368212215+=3439+249101352+=3399+142222931+=31299+142224185+=3399+102236836+251111396+=3459+258344741+254252812+254274512+261374305+367408433+3246017212+=3259+105014431+=3459+159376262+1593593510+=3139+237090586+197062826+=3199+1422133710+=3459+1422314310+=3979+190070126+2160820320+=3259+2160433520+=3399+142005961+1593904412+FF+FFFFFF+
```

Comment: Replace the regexp `=\d+\+` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, to remove all `+=39759` from your string use this regex:

- search: `\+=\d+`
- replace: (empty string)
- check the "Regular expression" checkbox
- do a "Replace All"